# Are there any region-based server limits in ArmA2?

Tags: region-lock, arma-2

I am planning to buy ArmA2 (since I keep hearing and reading great things about the game!), yet I'd first like to check whether it is possible for players of versions bought in different places (e.g. Steam, D2D, boxed copy) to play together, and also whether there are are any region-based limits to multiplayer games?

The best (cheapest ;)) option for buying for me it to buy it boxed here in Ukraine (it is a legal copy), but I'd like to be able to recommend it to friends and play with them, so I'd appreciate any feedback on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are absolutely no limits on multiplayer gameplay in ArmA2, or gameplay between versions distributed differently.

Comment: Thanks, I will look for an opportune moment to buy this, then :)

Comment: ...or I'll invest time into ArmA2:Arrowhead demo, it does have multiplayer, a great move to show the game to those not sure if it is too hard for them or not.